# How to check if 'enter' key was pressed with 'shift' key in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, shift, enter

I know that the `shift key` code is `16`, and the `enter key` code is `13`.

```
//@ catching any 'enter' keypress in textarea.
    function textareaOnEnter(){
        $('textarea#someId').keypress(function(e)
        {
          if(e.which == 13)
          {
            //.. works only for 'enter'
          }
        });     
    }
```

I thought it could be as simple as this:

```
    function textareaOnShiftAndEnter(){
        $('textarea#someId').keypress(function(e)
        {
          if(e.which == 13 && e.which == 16)
          {
            //.. don't work for nothing
          }
        });     
    }
```

But of course it simply doesn't work as I would expected. How do I check for `shift + enter` key press?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey

Comment: `e.which` could never be both 13 and 16 at the same time :P. You want modifier keys as @Amadan explains quite succinctly below :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey)
```

Shift, Ctrl and Alt are modifier keys, that get their own flags in the event data.